# Python flask google-app-engine file upload works in preview but fails in production FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I have a simple python flask file uploading app on google cloud app engine.

When running in development preview mode via

```
dev_appserver.py ./app.yaml
```

It works fine.  When run as a deployed production app via

```
gcloud app deploy ./app.yaml --project PROJECTNAME
```

It runs fine but on uploading the file to this form I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/USERNAME/python-docs-samples/appengine/standard_python37/hello_world/images/3d9c4a10a31c46e8a4166eddf659f4d7.jpg'
at save (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py:2725)
at upload_file (/srv/main.py:34)
```

The directory does exist, has very open permissions, and the upload works in preview mode but just not in production.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
    from werkzeug import secure_filename
    import uuid
    import logging
    unique_filename = str(uuid.uuid4().hex)
    import os
    app = Flask(__name__)
    UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/home/USERNAME/python-docs-samples/appengine/standard_python37/hello_world/images'
    app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

    @app.route('/upload', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
    def upload_file():
       if request.method == 'POST':
          f = request.files['file']
          fullfilename = (unique_filename + os.path.splitext(f.filename)[1])
          f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], secure_filename(fullfilename)))
    #      f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
          return 'file uploaded successfully'
```

Comment: Is this on App Engine standard? You can't write to the filesystem, you need to use Google Cloud Storage

Answer (score 1):

In the 2nd generation GAE standard environment (python 3.7) writing to the filesystem is allowed, but only to the `/tmp` directory and the written files *might* not be visible across requests. From [File system access](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#file_system_access):

> Files can be temporarily written to `/tmp`. Note that files written to
>   `/tmp` may not be available across subsequent requests to your app.

So your attempt to point `UPLOAD_FOLDER` under `/home` won't work **at all**.

If you move it under `/tmp` it may work sometimes, but **not all the times**: the later request trying to access a successfully uploaded and saved file *might* not find it.

As @Alex commented - storing the uploaded file into [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-cloud-storage) is the better/official approach.

Comment: How exactly would you store the uploaded file to cloud storage? The docs show how to read/write to GCS, but how do you store the uploaded file itself?

Comment: @claudiadast I'm uncertain if you can just copy the /tmp file over to a cloud storage bucket, but in the worst case you could just write a cloud storage file with the same content as the uploaded file (read from one and write to the other).